# Using a mock to override Aws\S3\S3Client in a Codeception test with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, mocking, codeception

In the past when testing code I would use the actual external services. However, I'm now trying to improve my tests and use mocks for external services. I'm trying to mock `Aws\S3\S3Client` in a Codeception functional test.

```
  public function shouldDownloadAFileFromS3(FunctionalTester $I): void {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents(codecept_data_dir('test-data.txt'));

    $stub = \Codeception\Stub::make(\Aws\S3\S3Client::class, [
      'getObject' => \Codeception\Stub\Expected::once($file_contents)
    ], $this);
    $I->getContainer()->set(\Aws\S3\S3Client::class, $stub);

    $I->amOnPage('/app/download/test-data.txt'); // <- fails here
    $I->seeInSource($file_contents);
  }
```

However, when I run the test the mock isn't used and the test fails because I'm passing in a fake file path which does not exist in the S3 bucket.

What's the right way to mock `Aws\S3\S3Client` in Codeception for Symfony 5.4?

Comment: I would assume, that `getContainer` gets you a different container, namely the [TestContainer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/TestContainer.php). I would see, if `$i->_getContainer()` is the correct one. But since it's not quite clear, which of the many libraries that exist are being used, this is only a best guess. Depending on how the s3client is injected, you might have to look at `bin/console debug:container` if some alias or something is being used, which might still reference another s3client

Comment: @Jakumi There is no `$I->_getContainer()`. `Call to undefined method FunctionalTester::_getContainer`

Comment: @Jakumi I've had a look at `bin/console debug:container` for both `prod` and `test` and `Aws\S3\S3Client` doesn't appear in either, yet it works in `prod` and `dev`. It also works in `test` in that it tries to use the actual service, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: my bad, what does `bin/console debug:container --show-hidden aws` output? finally, how is the s3client used in your code? anything special? also ... what does `dd(get_class($I->getContainer()))` output? to be honest, I've never used codeception with symfony (because I somewhat despise codeception since it provides no benefits in my view, but produces another weird layer of abstraction)

Comment: @Jakumi It only shows the service that we wrote to interface with the AWS library. If I could mock our own service that would solve the problem too, but it's private.